# Pass a value for an input prompt

Tags: bash, shell-script, pipe, forwarding

I do `unzip my.zip` and if files already exists it asks `replace myfile.ext [y]es, [n]o, [A]ll, [N]one, [r]ename:`

How can I force input for when the command prompts for input? I am aware `unzip` may have force flag but I am interested in passing an input.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you're looking for the `yes` command :

```
yes | unzip my.zip
```

It sends `y` to the output again and again. If you want to send something else, specify it as the argument:

```
yes n | unzip my.zip
```

You can also use `echo` if there's only one question:

```
echo no | unzip my.zip
```